# Dojo: What event fires when the page/window loses focus?

Tags: javascript, dojo, focus

In the javascript framework Dojo, is there an event that fires when the entire page loses focus?

If there is no event fired, is there another way to track the window losing focus? I want to be able to tell when someone clicks away from the page so that i can log the action (its an educational project, we're monitoring students actions for patterns and such).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is commonly known as the `blur` event.

This can be done in straight JavaScript, no need for `Dojo` here:

```
window.onblur = function() {
   //do something here...
};
```

Comment: Haha, one of those really basic things i just haven't picked up on yet. Thanks!